# StoryBoard - Set Target Name from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have StoryBoard in resources

```xml
  <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Fading" Storyboard.TargetName="NotifyWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
  </Window.Resources>
```

And on WindowClosing I have next code

```
private void NotifyWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard fading = this.Resources["Fading"] as Storyboard;
    if (fading != null && !fadingCompleted)
    {
        fading.Completed += FadingStoryBoard_Completed;
        fading.Begin();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void FadingStoryBoard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   fadingCompleted = true;
   Close();
   fadingCompleted = false;
}
```

And this works fine, But I want to move this storyboard to another assembly. So i need to specify `StoryBoard.TargetName` form code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Attached properties can be set from code via static helper methods named: `"Set" + PropertyName`

See C# example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname.aspx):

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(yourAnimation, "NotifyWindow");
```

Answer (score 8):

The standard way to set dependency properties to dependency objects is the same for attached properties :

```
dependencyObjectInstance.SetValue(SampleClass.PropertyName + "Property", value);
```

In your example :

```
fading.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, "NotifyWindow");
```