# How can a UserControl change its own size using a Storyboard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, user-controls, storyboard

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app and I am trying to create a UserControls that changes its own size when selected. The change between Selected/NotSelected is done using the VisualStateManager. To keep the following example simple I skip this and react to tap on the UserControl directly.

The Problem is, that I cannot find any way to change the size of the UserControl using a Storyboard since I do not know how to reference the UserControl itself in the Storyboard.TargetName property:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Namespace.MyUserControl"
    ...
    Tap="UserControl_Tap">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Expand">
            <DoubleAnimation To="400" Storyboard.TargetName="????" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Collaps">
            ...
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Rectangle x:Name="TestRect" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

private void UserControl_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) {
    if (Width < 400) {
        Storyboard storyBoard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["Expand"];
        storyBoard.Begin();

        Width = 400;
        Height = 400;
    } else {
        Storyboard storyBoard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["Collaps"];
        storyBoard.Begin();

        Width = 200;
        Height = 200;
    }
}
```

The Storyboards need to specify **Storyboard.TargetName**. What should be used instead of **????** to reference the UserControl itself? Using "**this**" does not work and throws an InvalidOperationException "Cannot resolve TargetName this". Same happens when using "**Namespace.MyUserControl**".

Using "**LayoutRoot**" as TargetName does not throw any exception but it does not work either: Nothing happens.

Animating any subcontrol inside the UserControl (e.g. TestRect using Storyboard.TargetName=TestRect") work without any problem. Also setting Width and Height directly without any storyboard work without any problem.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: why dont you create the storyboard in your target page, this way the user control is defined by its properties

Comment: The UserControl should be used on many different pages and the behaviour should always be the same. Wouldn't be better to implement the behaviour once (inside the UserControl) instead of doing this on every single page that uses the UserControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that I did not know how a Storybard inside "UserControl" can reference the control itself. As I know found out the answer is quite simple: Any element inside the UserControl would be targeted by its name, so just give the UserControl a name and it can be targeted as well:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Namespace.MyUserControl"
    x:Name="_this"      <-- NAME GIVEN HERE CAN BE USED AS TAGETNAME FOR STORYBOARD
    ...
    Tap="UserControl_Tap">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Expand">
            <DoubleAnimation To="400" Storyboard.TargetName="_this" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Collaps">
            ...
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Rectangle x:Name="TestRect" Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT ON 11/15/2013**

Be carefull about using this solution. I used it on a PhonePage to let it reference it selfe and placed a UserControl on this page which used the same solution. Thus both the page and the UserControl hat the **x:Name=_this**

From time to time the app crashed with a **System.InvalidCastException** saying that "MyPageType" could not be casted to "MyUserControlType". It took me a while to figure out what caused this problem. **The elements should not share the same x:Name.**

Using x:Name=thisMyPage and x:Name=thisMyControl instead solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is just an idea, but can you try it please.

When the target event occurred cast the animation from the control to variable, what do i mean by that:

```
private void SomeEventOccured(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   var sb = _customUserControl.Expand;
   sb.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath(CustomUserControl.WidthProperty));
   sb.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, _customUserControl.Name);
   sb.Begin();
 }
```

Or you can set your animation as `Application.Resources`

```
Storyboard sb = (Application.Current as App).Resources["Expand"] as Storyboard;
```

and then set `TargetNameProperty` and `TargetPropertyProperty`;

*P.S. i have tried it with my CustomUserControl the TargetProperty was Opacity. I hope this may help you [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301018/storyboard-set-target-name-from-code-behind)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I think your solution might work. Meanwhile I found a simpler solution. I will add it as answer, just in case anyone else has the same problem