# Storyboard animation not able to change TargetNameProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, storyboard

i am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.0 in VS2012 with C#

There are 16 pictures , and i want to do a **Fade Animation** - Decreasing `Size` and `Opacity` properties for every picture when the user **Taps** on it

but a `Storyboard` targets only 1 picture at a time , so i need to change the `TargetNameProperty` of the `Storyboard` each `Tap Event` and that's what i did

According to MSDN : [Working with Animations Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189069%28VS.95%29.aspx)

**Section : Dynamically Changing TargetName**

My code:

> XAML

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="FadeAnim">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="lt1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="53"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="20"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="lt1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="53"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="20"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="lt1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="16"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="lt1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="20"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="lt1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

        <Image x:Name="lt2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="59,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Source="/Assets/Letters/b.png" Tap="lt_Tap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Image x:Name="lt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="1,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Source="/Assets/Letters/a.png" Tap="lt_Tap" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="lt4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="112,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Source="/Assets/Letters/c.png" Tap="lt_Tap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Image x:Name="lt3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="171,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Source="/Assets/Letters/d.png" Tap="lt_Tap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Image x:Name="lt5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="224,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Source="/Assets/Letters/e.png" Tap="lt_Tap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Image x:Name="lt6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="283,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Source="/Assets/Letters/f.png" Tap="lt_Tap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
.
.
.
.
```

> C#

```
 private void img_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = sender as Image; 
            FadeAnim.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, img.Name);
            FadeAnim.Begin();     
        }
```

**Problem :** No matter on what image i tap , it plays the animation of the first picture always.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace and inner exception if it has one?

Comment: It looks like the problem is your setting the storyboard's target name but the story board target name you set on the double animation using key frames most likely isn't being updated. Try binding the Storyboard.targetname on the animations using relative source to the storyboard then setting the target name and see if that solves your problem. Also add FadeAnim.Stop() before begin() to make sure it's stopped before you try to begin it again.

Comment: @CalebB i also assigned names for the `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` with da1,da2,da3,da4 and changed them in the code , it didn't even showed the first animation and gave crashed with the same exception

Comment: @CalebB and i don't know how to do a stack trace

Comment: Can you add the exception? Did you add the storyboard.stop() before beginning it again? Finally, looking over the ms article I don't think you should be setting the target name on the animation itself, just the story board. In VS2012 when the exception is thrown a window should come up where you can get exception details and scroll down to stack trace. Or catch the exception and break, it will be a property of the exception thrown.

Comment: Could you show us XAML code of animated elements?

Comment: @CalebB ops , you were right , i forgot to make it stop after being Completed , now it doesn't crash but still , it's playing the animation of the first picture always

Comment: Try to replace this line `FadeAnim.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, img.Name);` with this: `Storyboard.SetTarget(FadeAnim, img);`

Comment: In addition to @ŁukaszRejman 's suggestion try invoking this action with the thread dispatcher: `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {Do work}));` the target may indeed be getting updated but the event may not be getting raised.

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman crashing with `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Use Storyboard.settargetname instead of set target. [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301018/storyboard-set-target-name-from-code-behind) may be good to look over.

Comment: A think you should remove these `Storyboard.TargetName="lt1"` in all places and add one in `<Storyborard  Storyboard.TargetName="lt1>`

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman still `InvalidOperationException` crashing

Comment: @CalebB but i did exactly what they are saying in the answers

Comment: Could you show us the XAML of your images?

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman i updated to `FadeAnim.SetValue(NameProperty, img.Name);` and it doesn't crash now , but still playing the first picture always

Comment: You have to add this `<Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>` to all images.

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman why so ?

Comment: Because you want to animate it.

Comment: For now you have it only in one image. Each image needs its own RenderTransform.

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman you were right , it works now , but the strange this is : if all the other images didn't have `RenderTransform` wouldn't the Storyboard show nothing instead of playing animation of the first picture ?

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman If you resolved the issue would you mind posting an answer for future viewers? Also Gabourx, I would set in the template the default target name to { x: Null } so then if the animation doesn't change for some reason it will not animate instead of animating the first image and implement error handling accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Image` needs its own `RenderTransform` in order to animate them separately. So you have to add this code to all images:

```
<Image.RenderTransform> 
    <CompositeTransform/> 
</Image.RenderTransform>
```

Also when you bind the animation to different images, you can do it simpler just by referencing the image itself instead of using name.

```
Image img = sender as Image;
if (img != null)
{
    FadeAnim.Stop(); // Stop previous animation
    Storyboard.SetTarget(FadeAnim, img);
    FadeAnim.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add in the FadeAnim.Stop() before Beginning the animation again or else it will throw an exception/break.